# Active Reports DataField Decimal rounding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, activereports

In active reports I have specified "TotalOT" for the datafield and then set the summary function to "sum".

This correctly totals up all of the "TotalOT" fields, however it automatically rounds them up.

I have the output format set as "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)" but a total of 89.76 is displayed as 89.80

Is there a way to prevent this without doing the calculations in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around with this for ages and finally managed to get the format/rounding correct by setting the output format as: #,##0.##;(#,##0.##)